# Perl Assigning Array to hash reference

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

So if i run this script it works the first time but when i try to add another value to the array and then assign the array back to the hash reference it gives me the value of ARRAY(0x9bd8254) as the values in the array.

the three lines in question

```
@addedvalue =  @{$state{$ustate}}{largest_city}  ;
push @addedvalue, $city;
$state{$ustate}{largest_city} =  \@addedvalue;
```

I assume I'm doing something wrong in the last line. As i print out the array before i do the last line and it looks fine. But i am unable to determine what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be great.

Thanks.

Comment: Use the Perl debugger to examine the values at each step.  Post a copy of the debug session.

Answer (score 3):

Hashes can only contains scalars, so you used a reference to an array (rather than array) as the value of the hash element.

But when it came time to print, you printed the value of the hash element rather than the elements of the array referenced by the value of the hash element.

```
$state{$ustate}{largest_city} = \@addedvalue; 
print("@{ $state{$ustate}{largest_city} }\n");
```

or

```
$state{$ustate}{largest_city} = \@addedvalue; 
print(join(', ', @{ $state{$ustate}{largest_city} }), "\n");
```

But it seems weird that you `largest_city` requires an array. The following would make more sense.

```
$state{$ustate}{largest_city} = $city; 
print("$state{$ustate}{largest_city}\n");
```